# Regular Expression to Ignore html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to match regular expressions in the text of an HTML document. 
1) The html is well formatted, and 
2) there are no '<>' symbols that aren't html tags.
The problem I have is that I *need to know the indexes of the matches in the original html document*, because I need to turn the matches into links in the original document. What this means is that I can't just extract the text using beautiful soup or some other parser. Because matches in the result of that parsing would have a different index. I can't just match on the html document either because some of the tags literally appear in the middle of a word, breaking the regex. I need a way to either:
1) map the indexes of matches in a parsed document to positions in the original document or,
2) Get my regexes to just ignore any tags and keep searching.

I'm using python re flavor. 
I've seen this question: [skip over HTML tags in Regular Expression patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732465/skip-over-html-tags-in-regular-expression-patterns) but it is different because that OP wants to ignore whitespaces in the context of a tag. The answers there did not give me a solution.

Here's a (very simplified) example. Is there a way to match:

```
r'(hello world)'
```

In the string:

```
string = "<p>hell</p>o world"
```

Where match.start will return 3?

Thanks!

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  - This should be automatically posted whenever a question has the tags `regex` and `html`.

Comment: Theoretically, [yes](http://rextester.com/HHV81772). Not sure if it is practical.

Comment: Haha, okay that is pretty brute force. Let me try it on my regexes and see whether my computer blows up or not.

Comment: Yea okay it isn't practical in the more general case because it breaks escapes and causes multiple repeats.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence @FHTMitchell :-|

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came up with a solution myself:

```
import re 

test_html = r'font></font><font face="Tahoma"><font size="4"> alleging that </font></font><font face="Tahoma"><font size="4">soldiers of the Uganda Peoples <span class="scayt-misspell" data-scayt_word="Defence" data-scaytid="32">Defence</span>'


NOT_TAG_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?<=\>)[^<>]+(?=\<)')


def create_chunks(html: str = None):
    """
    Divides an html string into the
    text chunks between tags, while
    storing the start and end indexes of the text
    in both the origional html string, and in the string
    that will be formed by concatenating the text in
    all the chunks.
    """
    matches = NOT_TAG_REGEX.finditer(html)

    text_cursor = 0
    chunks = []
    for match in matches:
        chunk = {
            "text": match.group(),
            "html_start": match.start(),
            "html_end": match.end(),
            "txt_start": text_cursor
        }
        text_cursor += match.end() - match.start()
        chunk["txt_end"] = text_cursor
        chunks.append(chunk)
    return chunks


def to_html_indx(txt_indx, chunks):
    """
    Given the index of a regex match in a string formed from 
    html, returns the index of that same string in the 
    origional html document
    """
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk["txt_start"] <= txt_indx <= chunk["txt_end"]:
            txt_indx_in_txt_chunk = txt_indx - chunk["txt_start"]
            html_indx = txt_indx_in_txt_chunk + chunk["html_start"]
            return html_indx
    else:
        print("some error message")
        return None


def main():
    chunks = create_chunks(test_html)
    text = "".join(chunk["text"] for chunk in chunks)
    print(text)
    example_regex = re.compile(r'that soldiers of')
    matches = example_regex.finditer(text)

    for match in matches:
        print("text match: " + match.group())
        txt_start = match.start()
        txt_end = match.end()
        html_start = to_html_indx(txt_start, chunks)
        html_end = to_html_indx(txt_end, chunks)
        print("html match: " + test_html[html_start: html_end])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This produces:

```
text match: that soldiers of

html match: that </font></font><font face="Tahoma"><font size="4">soldiers of
```